# how to view "localhost" on my iPod touch

Tags: iphone, localhost

I have a website I am building on localhost:

http://localhost/my-website

I need to test it on my iPhone, but I'm not sure how to go about it. Do I just change my httpd-vhosts.conf file, and, if so, what are the settings?

Comment: Just use the iPhone simulator's safari?

Comment: If you are using an Angular app then you can run `ng serve --host 192.168.1.10`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Assuming that your development machine is called `my-macbook-pro`, you should just be able to navigate to `http://my-macbook-pro.local/mywebsite` on your iPhone.

Comment: is my-macbook-pro my username? I just tried that...but doesn't work.

Comment: If you go to the terminal it should be the text before the colon.

Comment: To get the "computer-name" (in this case `my-macbook-pro`) type in terminal `scutil --get ComputerName`. To get the "user-name" `whoami`.

Comment: WOW. It works, and I can't believe it. This is so much easier than the couple hours I just spent hacking my DD-WRT router to enable me to do something similar. :-)

Comment: I ended up using this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41857012/470749

Answer (score 21):

To expand slightly on Richard J. Ross III's answer, "localhost" is a name used to refer only to the local computer. In order for your iPhone to be able to access content on that machine it must:

1. **Have an IP address on the same network as the server machine.**

   This can be achieved by connecting the iPhone to a wireless access point that is on the same network as the PC, or by creating an ad-hoc wireless network between the two devices.
2. **Respond to HTTP requests from network clients.**

   Assuming the server and the iPhone are on the same network, it should be possible for traffic to flow between them. However in order for your web content to be visible to the iPhone, the web server must also be configured to respond to requests made to the server machine's IP address.

   This is not normally a problem as web servers are commonly configured to respond to HTTP requests sent to any of the machines IP addresses. It is possible that a server could be configured to only respond to local requests, however this is not a typical default setting

   How you check or modify this setting is dependent upon the HTTP server software you are using. As this information is not specified I will include instructions for Apache2 as this is a very common choice of HTTP server.

#### Apache's Listen Directive

Apache's main configuration file is `httpd.conf` and it is located in the `conf` subdirectory of your Apache directory. The location of your Apache root directory will vary depending upon what operating system you are using and whether or not a custom location was chosen at installation.

The httpd.conf file contains a directive named Listen which controls the interface (IP address and port) on which Apache listens for incomming HTTP requests.

The default form of this directive is commonly

`Listen 80`

This specifies that the machine will respond on any of it's IP addresses to requests made on port 80, which is the default port for HTTP traffic.

You can modify the Listen directive to use any address associated with the machine including the loopback address (`127.0.0.1`) which the name `localhost` resolves to.

If Apache is set up to only listen on the loopback address then your server machine will only respond to requests made on the local machine. In this configuration, your Listen directive will look something like:

`Listen 127.0.0.1:80`

If this is the case, you will need to change to either listening on all addresses, as in the example above, or listening only on the address used by the iPhone to communicate with the server machine.

Answer (score 3):

## 100% working solutions

#### (for linux + apache + vhosts)

If you are using vhost (several sites on the same server apache) the next several tips can help you view your local websites on mobile:

**1) VHOST edit** -You should go to /etc/apache2/sites-available/ on your server. There can be several files `.conf`, each file contain a virtual host configuration for apache. Default file will look like 000-default.conf. Open it (or another one) with admin permissions `sudo`. In that file you should see something like this:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName auction.dev
        ServerAdmin test@test.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html/html
        ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/logs/access.log combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

**2) XIP.IO** - this special service (its totally free) can help you. You should add to `.conf` file next line - `ServerAlias auction.dev.*.xip.io`, after this operation your file will look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName auction.dev
            ServerAlias auction.dev.*.xip.io
            ServerAdmin test@test.com
            DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html/html
            ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error.log
            CustomLog /var/www/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

After editing you should save this file and restart apache with command `sudo apachectl restart`.

**3) View from mobile** - You need to know ip of your server, in my situation ip = 192.168.1.247. Now in your mobile browser just type auction.dev.192.168.1.247.xip.io and you should see your local website.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with xampp. localhost works on port 8080.
I just find my ip with ipconfig and surf to `http://10.0.0.1:8080`. 
That easy!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a better feel of the native behavior instead of just browser dev tools you can use the iOS simulator and type localhost:xxxx in safari app.

Answer (score 1):

For OSX, go to System Preferences / Sharing. There, you can find and change the name of your computer. In the same section, you also have to enable "Internet Sharing" service with "iPhone USB" port.

Then you can view your website at http://{ computer_name }.local/my-website.

Comment: This is the way to go if you are using a vpn and the page you wanna visit is only accessible through it!

Answer (score 0):

When you connect your ipod with the cable to your macbook the device appears in safari on your mac in the menu under developers. When you click this option you can see exact the same as you can on your ipod.

Answer (score 0):

Following these steps worked for me:

https://mtm.dev/iphone-localhost-mac

It is based on `Internet Sharing via USB` and setting & using the `device_name` which is then used as mentioned as `<device_name>.local:<port>`